# Force layout jumpiness/jitter on node click

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm making a force layout a network representation. I added functionality to display data about the node on('click') and another to highlight neighboring nodes on('dblclick'). Drag is also enabled and I don't have any mouseover effects.

The issue I'm having is with nodes jittering when the mouse is hovered over them, and a jumpiness when I try to click: the node seem to move slightly away from the mode when it is approached by the mouse, and shifts position back-and-forth as soon as there is a click and the whole graph ripples.
Often this will make my dblclick effect not work since the second click will miss the node. 
Where is this behavior originating and how do I fix it so I can click my nodes in peace? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you please put this up on fiddle...however i ll ask you to read about node getting fixed using fixed:true something like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558

Comment: I cant put up the data im using to generate the graph on fiddle, and it seems this behavior only happens for certain very crowded graphs. However, I found the issue was also discussed here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/qJQuCX1ZhjM